# Ng - click is not normal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

About NG, put a instruction `ng-click` in `div` tags, and then click, at this time to a second page (these are the two controllers), but after arriving to the second page, immediately jump to return to the `ng-click` page (this time without any operation);
But when I put this `ng-click` in a a tag, it's normal to jump.
What is the specific reason? This makes me very distressed!

Comment: are you sure this is not a coding error, show a jsfiddle highlighting this error

Comment: I'm sure it's not. If it's wrong, it's wrong